# Creating lines in excel with Loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hello I have a column of customers and a column of rewards they have available. I need to loop through the rewards and add a singular line containing the customer # to a new sheet. So For the example, the first customer would have 30,855 lines on the sheet with the customer # 3025480 in column A.

[image]

I don't have a lot  of experience in vba and the problem is so particular that I'm having trouble finding help. So I am hoping you folks can assist.

Thank you

Comment: How much data are you working with? You may run out of available rows pretty fast.

Comment: ill have a total of 3 million lines which means I'll have to break it apart into 3 or 4 sheets but ill do that before I run the script.

Comment: loop A2:A5; create new sheet for each cell, write column A value in new sheet to range("A1").Resize(colum B number,1).Value = column a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an inefficient way to using loops. The outer loop goes through each customer and the inner loop has one iteration for each reward.

```
Public Sub MakeRewards()
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long
    
    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A2:A5").Cells 'loop through all the customers
        For i = 1 To rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'create a loop to go from 1 to whatever number is in the next cell
            lCnt = lCnt + 1 'Keep track of what row you're on in Sheet2
            Sheet2.Cells(lCnt, 1) = rCell.Value 'Write the customer number to sheet2
        Next i
    Next rCell
    
End Sub
```

That takes a few seconds with just the data you have. It's not too fast and I wouldn't use it. But since you said you're not familiar with VBA, I think it's instructive to know the brute-force way to do it even if you don't use it.

Here's a better way. It reads the Excel range into an array (faster) and writes the customer number out all in one shot (way faster). This ran in a blink.

```
Public Sub MakeRewards2()
    
    Dim vaValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long
    
    vaValues = Sheet1.Range("A2:B5").Value
    lCnt = 1
    
    For i = LBound(vaValues, 1) To UBound(vaValues, 1)
        Sheet2.Cells(lCnt, 1).Resize(vaValues(i, 2)).Value = vaValues(i, 1)
        lCnt = lCnt + vaValues(i, 2)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there, that seems to work perfectly. Thank you so much for this. You have helped save me countless hours.

Answer (score 1):

### Creating Lines

- Copy the code into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.
- Adjust the values in the **const**ants section.
- `ThisWorkbook` means the workbook containing this code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createReward()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRowColumn As Variant = "A"              ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Dim srcCols As Variant: srcCols = Array("A", "B") ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A2"
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    
    ' Define Last Row Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = src.Columns(LastRowColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    Set rng = src.Range(src.Cells(FirstRow, LastRowColumn), rng)
    
   ' Write values from Source ranges to Source arrays.
    Dim ubc As Long: ubc = UBound(srcCols)
    Dim Source As Variant: ReDim Source(0 To ubc)
    Dim Target As Variant: Dim j As Long
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        For j = 0 To ubc
            Source(j) = rng.Offset(, src.Columns(srcCols(j)).Column _
                                   - src.Columns(LastRowColumn).Column).Value
        Next j
    Else
        ' Borrowed Target to create 1 by 1 array.
        ReDim Target(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        For j = 0 To ubc
            Source(j) = Target
            Source(j)(1, 1) = rng.Offset(, src.Columns(srcCols(j)).Column _
                            - src.Columns(LastRowColumn).Column).Value
        Next j
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Source arrays to Target array.
    Dim ubs As Long: ubs = UBound(Source(0))
    Dim ubt As Long: ubt = Application.Sum(Source(1))
    ReDim Target(1 To ubt, 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, Curr As Variant
    For j = 1 To ubs
        Curr = Source(0)(j, 1)
        For i = 1 To Source(1)(j, 1)
            k = k + 1
            Target(k, 1) = Curr
        Next i
    Next j
    
    ' Write values from Target array to Target range.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(tgt.Rows.Count _
                                 - tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Row).ClearContents
    tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(ubt).Value = Target
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Reward template created.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```